# Javascript: How to change the pathname in the URL

Tags: javascript, url

I have a page with infinite scroll view by ajax. On fetching the next set of data, I need to change the pathname in the URL without reloading the page through javascript.

Considering a URL https://example.com/products/page/2.

I need to change this URL to https://example.com/products/page/3 when the next set of objects are fetched on scroll.

I know the search params can be modified this way by this code

```
var url = new URL(location.href);
url.searchParams.set('page', '2');
url.search = url.searchParams.toString();
var new_url = url.toString(); 
window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', new_url);
```

I wanted to know how to do the same with the pathname and not the search params. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) of the url and use string manipulation to change the endpoint.

```
const url = new URL("https://example.com/products/page/3");
console.log(url.pathname);
// '/products/page/3'
```

> The pathname property of the URL interface is a USVString containing an initial '/' followed by the path of the URL (or the empty string if there is no path).

```js
const loc = "https://example.com/products/page/3";

const url = new URL(loc);

const pathnameArray = url.pathname.split('/');
pathnameArray[pathnameArray.length - 1] = parseInt(pathnameArray[pathnameArray.length - 1])+1;
url.pathname = pathnameArray.join('/');

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Setting the url pathname that way url.pathname = xyz; does not update the URL. I just need how to set the pathname and reflect it in browser without reloading the page.

Comment: It does change the URL referenced by `url`, if you want to see the change reflected in the browser you need to update the location using `location.replace(url)` or `location.assign(url)`

Comment: When I use location.replace(url) or location.assign(url), the page refreshes. I do not want that. I want it to work like url.searchParams.set('page', '2');

Comment: As indicated in the snippet `url.pathname = '/updated/pathname'` changes the `.pathname` value for the `URL` object reference by `url` just as `url.searchParams.set()` changes the `.search` value for that object. Of course replacing or assigning a location a new url will reload the page (this would be the case if you replaced it with the URL altered by `.searchParams.set` as well.)

Comment: Nope. Modify the search params using .set method does not reload the page. I am guessing its not possible to change the pathname without the page being reloaded